# How to get parameter from url in js?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the location in a URL (localhost: port/: location). For example, if the URL is `localhost:8080/show/myplace/` I want to extract `myplace`. 
How to do this in javascript?

Comment: `java` != `javascript`. From the `java` tag description: "*Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript) [...]*"

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
var location = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
```

This will return the part of URI you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that :

```
window.location.pathname
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an array of each pathname in the url:

```
window.location.pathname.split('/')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhd28cre/ (check your console log when running the example)